# I am trying to write a function that removes all the odd elements from a given linked-list and also returns

Tags: c, function, linked-list

an adress of a new list of the odd elements removed. I find this task quite complicated, and I would be happy if you could help to repair or improve my code.

Here is what I've done by far:

```
typedef struct list{
      int data;
      struct  list* next;
} List;


List* removeOddValues(List** source)
{
      List* curr= *source;
      List* prev;
      List* odd= NULL;

      while (curr)
      {
        if ((curr->data)%2==1)  //odd//
          {
           insertNodeToEnd(&odd, curr->data); //creating a new list of those odd elements//
           prev->next = curr->next;
          }
        else
          {
           prev = curr;
           curr= curr->next;
          }
      }
     return odd;   //returning the new list as wanted//
}

List* createNewNode(int newData, List*  next)
{
       List* newNode = (List)calloc(1, sizeof(List));
       newNode->data = newData;
       newNode->next = next;

       return newNode;
}

void insertNodeToEnd(List** list, type  newData) //insert a new node to list //
{
       LNode* newNode = createNewNode(newData, NULL);

    list->next= newNode;
```

Comment: Instead of creating a new node, you should use the existing odd node to save to the odd chain. In the current code it will be lost. (*leaked*)

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate linkedlist and on removing every odd element, insert that particular element to that LL. Also have the head reference of the new LL and return it. It will be a LL of entire removed odd elements.