# Uninitialized local variable error

Tags: c, function, linked-list

Here is the function which getting me into troubles and I actually can't understand why.
This function supposes to removes all the odd elements from a given linked-list and also returns an address of a new linked list of the odd elements removed.

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} Node;


Node* removeOddValues(Node **source)
{
    Node *curr = *source;
    Node *even;
    Node *even_curr;
    Node *odd;
    Node *odd_curr;
    Node *next;

    even->next=NULL;
    odd->next=NULL;
    even_curr = even;
    odd_curr = odd;

    while(curr)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = NULL;

        if(curr->data % 2!=0)// odd//
            odd_curr = odd_curr->next = curr;//node add to last//
        else                 //even//
            even_curr = even_curr->next = curr;

        curr = next;
    }
    *source= even->next;//update source//

    return odd->next;  //the new list of odd elements removed//
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'even' used
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'odd' used
```

Comment: You never initialize the variable `even`.

Comment: You didn't get an *error*, you got a *warning*. Actually two.

Comment: You are dereferencing `even` and `odd` to assign their `next` pointers to NULL but they have not been initialized

Comment: I think what you want is closer to `Node even ; even.next=NULL; even_curr = &even;`

Comment: so how should repair the errors and the code itself? I think I am stuck

Comment: @chux sorry I dont get what you mean

Comment: Repost of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43890168/2235885

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, you get warnings (and your program contains undefined behaviour and would probably crash) because you access/dereference uninitialised variables:

```
Node *even;
Node *odd;
even->next=NULL;  // even has not been initialised
odd->next=NULL;   // odd has not been initialised
```

Second, your code does not "remember" the roots of the new lists, i.e. you manage `odd_curr` and `even_curr`, each pointing to the last node of the respective list, but you do not have something like `odd_root` and `even_root`.

The following code shows how this could work. The logic for appending a node at the end while additionally considering a root node is the same for both lists, odd and even, and therefore factored out into a separate function:

```
void appendNode(Node **root, Node** lastNode, Node *curr) {
    if (!*root) {  // root not yet assigned?
        *root = curr;
        *lastNode = curr;
    } else {
        (*lastNode)->next = curr;  // append curr after lastNode
        *lastNode = curr;  // let curr become the lastNode
    }
    (*lastNode)->next = NULL; // terminate the list at lastNode
}

Node* removeOddValues(Node **source)
{
    Node *curr = *source;
    Node *evenRoot = NULL;
    Node *oddRoot = NULL;
    Node *evenLast = NULL;
    Node *oddLast = NULL;

    while(curr)
    {
       Node *next = curr->next;
       if(curr->data % 2!=0) {
          appendNode(&oddRoot, &oddLast, curr);
       }
       else {
          appendNode(&evenRoot, &evenLast, curr);
       }
       curr = next;
    }
    *source= evenRoot;
    return oddRoot;
}
```

Comment: Hm - I don't see a simpler way; maybe you can shorten the program by two or three lines (e.g. by using `*source` instead of `curr`, yet the logic and thus the complexity will probably remain the same...

Comment: Yes, it can be done simpler, with only two variables (just *podd and **ppodd), and without the helper function. (but the helper function and most of your varables would probably disappear, when inlined)

Answer (score 0):

```
curr = next;
```

Gives you the first warning, because `next` is not initialized.

```
odd_curr = odd;
```

Gives you the second warning, because `odd` is not initialized.

You should consider using `malloc` to allocate structures, because you are just allocating pointers, not the actual nodes. You can start learning more about linked lists from [this interactive guide.](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) Even if you somehow fix these two warnings, it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest case, using only two variables. The *even* nodes stay in the original list; the *odd* nodes are removed from the chain and returned as a linked list.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct llist {
        struct llist * next;
        int data;
        };

struct llist *chop_odds(struct llist **source)
{
struct llist *odd = NULL;
struct llist **target = &odd;

while ( *source) {
        if((*source)->data %2) { /* odd */
                *target = *source;         // steal the pointer
                *source = (*source)->next; // source skips this node
                target = &(*target)->next; // advance target
                }
        else source = &(*source)->next; /* even */
        }
*target = NULL;

return odd;
}
```