# Remove first node from a linked list and return it without allocating or deallocating memory.(C programming)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I am not allowed to deallocate memory or allocate new memory(the list has already been allocated for me). So in essence I am trying to write a function like,

```
struct node* returnAndRemoveFirstNode(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* returned = head;
    struct node* temp = head->next;
    returned->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    return returned;
}
```

This does not work, as when I set returned->next to null I am also setting head's next to null. I am not sure how to solve this problem, I am sure there are many ways to solve it just not sure how.
For a List in the form (1->2->3->4) both the original list and the returned node look like (1->Null)

```
//Here is the node struct in case you need it
//I am not allowed to alter the struct..
struct node{
int data;
struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: You need to receive a pointer to the head pointer, so you can reassign it if you're removing the first node.

Comment: @kronickrypt To remove all nodes that satisfy a condition and remove the first node are two different things. It seems you need not to return removed nodes. What you need is to free the removed nodes.

Comment: I am just using this example to break the problem down as this is the only case I am not getting correct. I am not allowed to free or allocate new nodes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/43925614/905902 (for instance)

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you that solved my problem. When I revised my solution using double pointers, I was trying to update the pointer to the head pointer when I needed to update the pointer that was being pointed to by double pointer.

Comment: I've not written a single C line, but it seems like this might help: Instead of creating "temp" pointer, move your head to head->next straight off. It would be ```returned = head```, then ```head = head->next``` and finally ```returned->next = NULL```.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you do not understand correctly the original task.

Nevertheless a function that removes the first node from the list and returns it can look the following way

```
struct node * returnAndRemoveFirstNode( struct node **head )
{
    struct node *returned = *head;

    if ( *head != NULL ) 
    {
        *head = ( *head )-next;
        returned->next = NULL;
    }

    return returned;
}
```

Pay attention to that in general the list can be empty. So the pointer to the head node can be equal to NULL.

If to follow the description in your comment

> The original task is to remove all nodes from the list that contain a
>   specific data and add all of those nodes to a different list and
>   return it.

then the function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int push_front( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void output( struct node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

struct node * remove_if( struct node **head, int cmp( int data ) )
{
    struct node *new_list = NULL;

    for ( struct node **current = &new_list; *head != NULL; )
    {
        if ( cmp( ( *head )->data ) )
        {
            *current = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }

    return new_list;
}

int odd( int data )
{
    return data % 2 != 0;
}

int even( int data )
{
    return data % 2 == 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    struct node *head = NULL;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; --i ) push_front( &head, i );

    output( head );

    putchar( '\n' );

    struct node *even_head = remove_if( &head, even );

    output( head );
    output( even_head );

    putchar( '\n' );

    struct node *odd_head = remove_if( &head, odd );

    output( head );
    output( odd_head );

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null

1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 9 -> null
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 10 -> null

null
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 9 -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node* returnFirstNode(struct node** head)
{
    struct node* returned = *head;
    struct node* next = (*head)->next;
    *head = next;
    returned->next = NULL;
    return returned;
}
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question?

Comment: @JonathanWood Yes, as I figured the solution out.

Comment: @kronickrypt The solution is incorrect. See  my answer. And I am sure you do not understand the original task.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't look right. For starters, if the list is empty and `head` is NULL, your use of `head->next` and `returned->next` is going to cause problems. Also, what is `(*head)->next`? I think that should just be `head->next`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The original task is to remove all nodes from the list that contain a specific data and add all of those nodes to a different list and return it. The case I was stuck on was WHEN REMOVING THE FIRST NODE. Теперь понятно?

Comment: @kronickrypt Your approach is invalid. There is no need to separate the task into several task.

Comment: @kronickrypt See my answer one more.

Comment: The code is *almost* correct. You should add a check for `*head` not being NULL before dereferencing `*head`